# Does it matter how my parents died?

Tags: pirate101

In pirate101, you choose from a variety of deaths of your parents including mutiny, shipwreck, armada, storm and squid attack.  Does this choice make any difference in what happens in the game?

Comment: Only if you want to be batman

Answer (score 2):

This question determines which Companion later joins your crew. This companion will be your fourth in game and you find them while raiding The Presidio for the quest Quid Pro Quo. 
Orphaned By

1. Mutiny! Dead Mike-Undead Pirate
2. Shipwrecked! Lucky Jack Russell-Dog Pirate
3. Armada! Gaspard de Vole-Guinea Pig Guard
4. Storm! Milo Graytail-Rat Brigand
5. Squid Attack! Birgus Latro-Crab Thug